# How do I force css grid items to overlap each other?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I have a row of 5 columns, each holding a red box with some text. When the user shrinks the screen sideways, I want the container to shrink sideways, and I want the boxes to start overlapping each other, so that the text in the boxes are still fully visible.
Not sure how to achieve this, I've tried changing the side margins of the boxes to negative but that doesn't seem to work too well.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid brown;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.playerRow {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  gap: 0.45em;
}

.playerBox {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.playerBox:nth-child(1),
.playerBox:nth-child(3),
.playerBox:nth-child(5)
{
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="playerRow">
    <div class="playerBox onTop">user 1 ahhahah</div>
    <div class="playerBox onTop">user 2 ahhahah</div>
    <div class="playerBox onTop">user 3 ahhahah</div>
    <div class="playerBox onTop">user 4 ahhahah</div>
    <div class="playerBox onTop">user 5 ahhahah</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/MH-123/pen/vYMJoZR

Comment: Overlapping will require some form of positioning/tramsform. CSS-Grid items will adhere to the grid and won't overlap.

Comment: Would I be able to make them overlap if I use flexbox?

Comment: No, same issue. Elements don't overlap by default. You have to layer them to get that effect and that requires either positioning or a transform with `z-index` in play.

Comment: hmm ok, so in this simplified version, I would have to remove display: flex (turns out the grid was redundant anyways), then place the player boxes with CSS top, bottom, left, right? so put position: absolute in player boxes and position: relative in playerrow?

Comment: @Paulie_D  Not necessarily  - two grid items can be in the same grid location quite easily.  BUT this seems to describe a pattern where the columns stack to rows - which is more a "responsive" setup rather than overlap Ref https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Responsive_Design

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Which part of the doc are you talking about specifically? One thing is I don't want text wrap at all. I want the text to go into the other boxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an extra element to the `.playerBox` and set a width to it.
Something like this:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid brown;
}

.playerRow {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  text-align: center;
}

.playerBox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  min-width: 0;
  background-color: red;
}

.playerBox span {
  width: 150px;
  flex: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 6;
  margin: 0 4px;
}

.playerBox:nth-child(odd) span {
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="playerRow">
    <div class="playerBox onTop"><span>user 1 ahhahah</span></div>
    <div class="playerBox onTop"><span>user 2 ahhahah</span></div>
    <div class="playerBox onTop"><span>user 3 ahhahah</span></div>
    <div class="playerBox onTop"><span>user 4 ahhahah</span></div>
    <div class="playerBox onTop"><span>user 5 ahhahah</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: One question though, how come when I take out the min-width: 0 from the playerbox, the boxes start to overflow from the playerrow?

Comment: `min-width: 0;` is for flex elements to shrink.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to calculate where each box is to be and position them absolute.

Here's a simple example.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid brown;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.playerRow {
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  --gap: calc((100vw - (5 * 150px)) / 10);
}

.playerBox {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ff000008;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc((var(--n) - 1) * 20%);
  left: calc((var(--gap) * var(--n)) + ((var(--n) - 1) * (150px + var(--gap))));
}

.playerBox:nth-child(1) {
  --n: 1;
}

.playerBox:nth-child(2) {
  --n: 2;
}

.playerBox:nth-child(3) {
  --n: 3;
}

.playerBox:nth-child(4) {
  --n: 4;
}

.playerBox:nth-child(5) {
  --n: 5;
}

.playerBox:nth-child(1),
.playerBox:nth-child(3),
.playerBox:nth-child(5) {
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="playerRow">
    <div class="playerBox onTop">user 1 ahhahah</div>
    <div class="playerBox onTop">user 2 ahhahah</div>
    <div class="playerBox onTop">user 3 ahhahah</div>
    <div class="playerBox onTop">user 4 ahhahah</div>
    <div class="playerBox onTop">user 5 ahhahah</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You may want to add a re-setting of the widths (to less than 150px) for when the viewport width gets too small and the overlaps interfere with the text too much.

Comment: Probably do not need absolute positioning (nor want it) for a "responsive" page design re: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Responsive_Design

Comment: Interesting, could you explain why not given the positioning is responsive?

Comment: But it only "collapses the gap" when I test it here...and once there it stops - none are above/below each other vertically.   I made it "full screen" and resized to very narrow

Comment: They are above each other when I try - have you removed the background color to see the text below? (what exactly the OP wants when they go one above the other in terms of this coloring of course we don't know, but if you want to see the text you need at least a bit of transparency of the background).

Comment: No I just ran the snippet" in full screen mode and made it narrow/collapsed horizontally - make no changes to your code.  I have Chrome BTW - but should not matter

Comment: My Chrome (Windows10) stops me going below a certain width when I just resize so I tested in devtools inspect and definitely get overlap. Mind you, I also get a bit of text overflow when things are really narrow, and the OP would have to describe what they want to happen when things get really tight.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss apparently Chrome doesn't allow the window to shrink below 400px (not that I can find a definitely reliable source for that asseertion, many people seem to say it and it's my experience) which explains why you didn't see overlap. devtools will let you though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option by adding row containers and making them flex we can space the rows etc. and still adjusts the row content to produce the effect desired.

Note this only collapses to the width of the row content.  This could be scaled but that probably gets more than just CSS in play - there are a number of questions existing for that so won't dive into that here.

I did re-structure the content to contain what were even/odd cells as "rows".

I did use the grid to do some "super center" of a few things and gap the rows.

Lots of borders and padding just to show what is where etc. for this demo.

Grid: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_grid_layout/Realizing_common_layouts_using_grids
nth-child: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

```css
body,
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
}

.player-container {
  /* super-center in the container */
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #00FF00;
  padding: 0.25em;
  width: 100%;
}

.player-row-container {
  /* super-center in the container */
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  row-gap: 0.25em;
  border: dashed #0000FF 1px;
  width: 100%;
}

.player-row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  border: solid #0DD0FF 1px;
  padding: 0.125em;
  width: 100%;
}

.player-row:nth-child(ODD) {
  color: #FF0000;
}

.player-row:nth-child(even) {
  color: #0000FF;
}

.player-box {
  /* super-center the text in the cell only */
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  min-height: 2em;
  background-color: #FF000020;
  border: solid 1px #FF0000;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: min-content;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="player-container">
  <div class="player-row-container">
    <div class="player-row">
      <div class="player-box">user 2 ahhahah</div>
      <div class="player-box">user 4 ahhahah</div>
    </div>
    <div class="player-row">
      <div class="player-box">user 1 ahhahah</div>
      <div class="player-box">user 3 ahhahah</div>
      <div class="player-box">user 5 I have a really long user name</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```